# Como copiar uma string em C?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro

O método a seguir que encontrei na internet, serve para criar uma cópia de string.:

```
char* bin_copy_string(const char* begin, const char* end) {
    char* result;
    result = malloc(end - begin);
    if (result) {   // result is a valid pointer, and not a null pointer
        char* p = result;
        while (begin != end) {
            *(p++) = *(begin++);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

A minha dúvida é na linha `char* p = result;` , por que o novo ponteiro `p` está modificando a string `result` mas no final retorna `result`? Não daria para apenas fazer `*(result++) = *(begin++);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ele não está modificando a *string* `result` porque `result` não é uma *string*, é uma variável e pode notar que em lugar algum essa variável é modificada.

Ele altera a variável `p` incrementando o ponteiro para ir andando caractere a caractere do objeto *string*. O mesmo acontece como ponteiro `begin` em sincronia.

Ele não altera `result` porque essa variável aponta para o início do objeto *string*. Quando terminar você quer retornar para o início do objeto e não para o fim, então não pode mexer nisso.

Você pode mudar do jeito que está pensando e ver o que acontece. Você retornará um valor que aponta para o terminador da *string* e por isso quando for usar não terá nada útil ali.

Essa função é suscetível a falhas se não usar de forma adequada, portanto pode não ser uma boa ideia usá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o `strdup` do `C`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *s="...........";
  char *s_copy=strdup(s); // this copies the string
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `strdup()` não faz parte da biblioteca padrão *C* é uma particularidade *POSIX*. Seria melhor usar o exemplo do AP com `strcpy()`.